# How Do I use .bind in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript

Still struggling to get my head around `.bind`.

If I have...

```
 dbAccess.runCommand('INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
                            req.getConnection,
                            email)()
                .then(setProjectPermission(req, res, 'insertId', projectId, permissionLevel));
```

and....

```
function setProjectPermission(req, res, arg, projectId, permissionLevel) {

  return function(result) {

    var id = result.rows[0][arg];

    ...
```

Can I use `.bind` so I don't have to use a function which returns a function? I'm struggling to know how to make the anonymous closure. For example if it was EC6 I would do this (I think)...

```
 dbAccess.runCommand('INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
                            req.getConnection,
                            email)()
                .then(result => setProjectPermission(req, res, result.insertId, projectId, permissionLevel));
```

and....

```
function setProjectPermission(req, res, idArg, projectId, permissionLevel) {

    var id = idArg;

    ...
```

Is this possible to do without returning the function which is expecting 'result' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example if it was EC6 I would do this (I think)...

("EC6" => "ES2015" aka "ES6") Yes, exactly, and all up-to-date versions of Node support arrow function syntax. Except that your `()` at the end are a bit dodgy:

```
dbAccess.runCommand('INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
                        req.getConnection,
                        email)()
// ---------------------------^^ These shouldn't be there, you've *already* called `runCommand`
            .then(result => setProjectPermission(req, res, result.insertId, projectId, permissionLevel));
```

So (apologies, I've also adjusted indentation):

```
dbAccess.runCommand(
        'INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
        req.getConnection,
        email
    )
    .then(result => setProjectPermission(req, res, result.insertId, projectId, permissionLevel));
```

If you need to run on legacy versions of Node, you can use `function` syntax:

```
dbAccess.runCommand(
        'INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
        req.getConnection,
        email
    )
    .then(function result {
        return setProjectPermission(req, res, result.insertId, projectId, permissionLevel);
    });
```

Since you're not using `this` in there, no need for `bind`.

If you **were** using `this` in there, you'd add `bind` to the end:

```
dbAccess.runCommand(
        'INSERT INTO users (email) values (?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',
        req.getConnection,
        email
    )
    .then(function result {
        return setProjectPermission(req, res, result.insertId, projectId, permissionLevel);
    }.bind(this)); // <===== `bind` is here
```

...or use `var _this = this;` and use `_this` instead, or any of the tricks described in [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). But with arrow functions, you don't have to worry about that, they *close over* `this`.

Comment: *(If you see some odd `()` in that, hit refresh.)*